# Check if exist in database mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

```
$check = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$check'";
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0)
{
 echo "1";
}
else 
{
echo "0";
}
```

I am trying to check if email exist in database, but whatever value I add for `if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0` I go only result `1` or `0` if the email exist or not.
Some ideas?

Comment: You are not executing the query, you are just defining a string.

Comment: ... What? You are checking whether it exists and you're only getting 1 or 0, depending if the email exists? Isn't that exactly the desired result?

Comment: @jeroen is right. You are not execute the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not running the sql statement by using `mysqli_query`

you must first query sql statement and then count row

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
/*mysqli connection*/

$check = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$check'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($res ) == 0){
    }
```

Comment: great work. please tick my answer if my answer solved your problem @qqq123

Answer (score 1):

Execute Your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$check'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $user_id;
  $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
  header('location: index.php');
}else {
  array_push($errors, "Wrong credentials");
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. `$results` is not defined in the original code

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.